# Div won't stay inside the realm of another Div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

I'd like to have the picture and the name be in the same line as the header... Without having to do manual margin-top...

Just to note... I am using Bootstrap.
http://getbootstrap.com/

Here is the HTML code...
[image]

Here is the CSS code...

```
.navbar-top {
    height: 64px;
    background-color: #772A75;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 64px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px #888888;
}

.navbar-container {
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.navbar-heading {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: A picture of your code is next to useless, please try to post the plaintext or use JSFiddle

Comment: Why is that the case? The gentleman below was able to figure it out? 
I was going to post the code but it wouldn't show properly so I just opted for the image. Just curious about your answer

Comment: For simple questions it's probably fine, but it's a good habit to get into- it makes it easier for users to tinker with the code, and makes it more likely to get a quality answer.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the feedback. That's definitely helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `float: left` for the left heading and set `float: right` for the right image block.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the **dropdown-toggle** after the h1 tag, make sure to add **display : inline-block** to both of them. you might have to play with floats and width to get them the way you want...